# Call function within callback with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Given the below:
https://github.com/Uepaa-AG/p2pkit-cordova

I am not figuring out how I'd call `onEnabled` for example. Not using `ts' the example obviously works great.

But now that I am working with TypeScript, I can't seem to call the nested functions properly.

I have this:
`cordova.plugins.p2pkit.enable("xyzzy", this.p2pkitCallback, function...`

```
p2pkitCallback() {
        onEnabled() {
          console.log('p2pkit enbled');
          cordova.plugins.p2pkit.enableProximityRanging()
          cordova.plugins.p2pkit.startDiscovery('', cordova.plugins.p2pkit.HIGH_PERFORMANCE) // base64 encoded Data (bytes)=
    }
```

onEnabled() is highlighted in red of course... 
How should I refactor the code?

Thanks!

Comment: there's an example on how to do it in the link you provided, ts is the same as js.. the first one actually... the code you pasted is not even valid js/ts.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass and call callback functions in Typescript as following;

Declare a callback function argument and call it asynchronous.

```
public generate(report: Report, callback: () => any = () => {}): void {
    this.generateReport(report, ReportType.PDF).then(callback);
}
```

Example of passing the callback to the function:

```
doFilter(payload): void {
    const callback = () => this.filter.hide();
    this.reportService.generate(payload.reportKey, callback);
  }
```

Note that in my example I optionally assign the callback variable to a noop function to prevent stuff from breaking when no callback is provided.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if he's going to fix the syntax for the onEnabled property he's going to be fine. :)